# Bootstrap collapse issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm working on this website http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/miete.html

As you can see i'm using "Bootstrap collapse" to hide and show the 4 tables in the middle. But now i've an issue:  when i click on the second button for example (EDI 40)automatically the first table will collapse too (see screen 1) how can i solve it?

this is the HTML and the CSS code

HTML

```
<div class="row">

                <!-- SINGLE TEXT -->
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="single-service text-left wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".6s">
                    <div class="service-title">
                    </div>
                    <div class="service-content">
                        <h3>Warum Mietdampfanlagen</h3>
                        <p>Sie kommen in einen Engpass, weil Ihre Dampfanlage nicht verfügbar ist (Unfall, Revision etc.) oder nicht genügend Kapazität hat!
                            Wir können Ihnen helfen dieses Manko zu überbrücken mit unseren mobilen, modularen Dampferzeugern. Rufen Sie uns an, wir sind für Sie da!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END SINGLE TEXT -->

        <!-- Columns Tabelle -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
       <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#table1" class="table1" style="margin-bottom: 20px; width: 100% !important; background: #fadf3e; color:#000;">Stritzel PS 200-15</button>
        <div id="table1" class="collapse">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="744">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>

                    <th>Kriterium</th>
                    <th>Einheit</th>
                    <th>Grösse</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Dampfleistung</td>
                    <td>kg/h</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Abmessung (lxbxh)</td>
                    <td>mm</td>
                    <td>1'020 x 600 x 1'370</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Gewicht</td>
                    <td>kg</td>
                    <td>140</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                    <td>Medium</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>Sattdampf</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                    <td>Ansprechdruck SV</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                    <td>6,0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                    <td>Einstellbereich Kessel</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                    <td>1,0 - 5,0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                    <td>max. Betriebsdruck</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                    <td>5,0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Fabr. Nr. </td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>21.301.112 / 05-09</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Gesamtanschluss</td>
                    <td>kW</td>
                    <td>elektrisch, 15 kW</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Stromanschluss</td>
                    <td>A / V</td>
                    <td>CEE 32A, 5-polig / 400 V</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Wasserenthärtung</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>separat mietbar</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Frostschutzsicherung</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>keine</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Mobilität</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>fahrbar</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Flexible Anschlussleitungen</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>nach Bedarf</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Wasseranschluss</td>
                    <td>Zoll</td>
                    <td>R 1/2" / AG</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Abwasseranschluss</td>
                    <td>Zoll</td>
                    <td>R 1/2" / IG</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Dampfanschluss</td>
                    <td>Zoll</td>
                    <td>3/4" / IG</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
       <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#table2" class="table1" style="margin-bottom: 20px; width: 100% !important; background: #fadf3e; color:#000;">EDI 40</button>
        <div id="table2" class="collapse">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="744">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>

                    <th>Kriterium</th>
                    <th>Einheit</th>
                    <th>Grösse</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Dampfleistung</td>
                    <td>kg/h</td>
                    <td>57</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Abmessung (lxbxh)</td>
                    <td>mm</td>
                    <td>1'205 x 660 x 1'425</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Gewicht</td>
                    <td>kg</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                    <td>Medium</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>Sattdampf</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                    <td>Ansprechdruck SV</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                    <td>13,0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                    <td>Einstellbereich Kessel</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                    <td>1,0 - 12,5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                    <td>Gesamtanschluss</td>
                    <td>kW</td>
                    <td>elektrisch, 40 kW</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Stromanschluss</td>
                    <td>A / V</td>
                    <td>CEE 63A, 5-polig / 400 V</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Wasserenthärtung</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>separat mietbar</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Frostschutzsicherung</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>keine</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Mobilität</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>fahrbar</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Flexible Anschlussleitungen</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>nach Bedarf</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Wasseranschluss</td>
                    <td>Zoll</td>
                    <td>R 1/2" / AG</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Dampfanschluss</td>
                    <td>Flanschen DN/PN</td>
                    <td>20 / 16</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Abwasseranschluss</td>
                    <td>Zoll</td>
                    <td>R 1/2" / IG</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Kondensatanschluss</td>
                    <td>Zoll</td>
                    <td>R 3/4" / AG</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Entlüfungsleitung</td>
                    <td>Zoll</td>
                    <td>R 1" / AG</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
       <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#table3" class="table1" style="margin-bottom: 20px; width: 100% !important; background: #000; color:#fadf3e;">PTS 21.200.15</button>
        <div id="table3" class="collapse">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="744">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Kriterium</th>
                    <th>Einheit</th>
                    <th>Grösse</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Dampfleistung</td>
                    <td>kg/h</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Abmessung (lxbxh)</td>
                    <td>mm</td>
                    <td>1'020 x 600 x 1'370</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Gewicht</td>
                    <td>kg</td>
                    <td>140</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                    <td>Medium</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>Sattdampf</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                    <td>Ansprechdruck SV</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                    <td>6,0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                    <td>Einstellbereich Kessel</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                    <td>1,0 - 5,0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                    <td>max. Betriebsdruck</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                    <td>5,0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Fabr. Nr. </td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>21.301.112 / 05-09</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Gesamtanschluss</td>
                    <td>kW</td>
                    <td>elektrisch, 15 kW</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Stromanschluss</td>
                    <td>A / V</td>
                    <td>CEE 32A, 5-polig / 400 V</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Wasserenthärtung</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>separat mietbar</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Frostschutzsicherung</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>keine</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Mobilität</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>fahrbar</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Flexible Anschlussleitungen</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>nach Bedarf</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Wasseranschluss</td>
                    <td>Zoll</td>
                    <td>R 1/2" / AG</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Abwasseranschluss</td>
                    <td>Zoll</td>
                    <td>R 1/2" / IG</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Dampfanschluss</td>
                    <td>Zoll</td>
                    <td>3/4" / IG</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
       <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#table4" class="table1" style="margin-bottom: 20px; width: 100% !important; background: #000; color:#fadf3e;">Container ZAG 881/882</button>
        <div id="table4" class="collapse">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="744">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Kriterium</th>
                    <th>Einheit</th>
                    <th>Grösse</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Dampfleistung</td>
                    <td>kg/h</td>
                    <td>560</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Abmessung (lxbxh)</td>
                    <td>mm</td>
                    <td>3'300 x 2'450 x 2'700</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Gewicht</td>
                    <td>kg</td>
                    <td>ca. 4'000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                    <td>Medium</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>Sattdampf</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                    <td>Ansprechdruck SV</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                    <td>13,0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                    <td>Einstellbereich Kessel</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                    <td>4,0 - 10.0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                    <td>max. Betriebsdruck</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                    <td>11,0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Feuerung</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>Heizöl extraleicht</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Wasserenthärtung</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>Doppelpendel-Anlage</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Kapazität Wasserenthärtung</td>
                    <td>m3/°d</td>
                    <td>120,0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Frostschutzeinrichtung</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>ja</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Fernüberwachung</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>optional</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Stromanschluss</td>
                    <td>A / V</td>
                    <td>CEE 32 A, 5 -polig/ 400  V</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Kaminanlage</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>Edelstahlkamin</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Kaminlänge</td>
                    <td>m</td>
                    <td>6,0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Flexible Anschlussleitungen</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>nach Bedarf</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Wasseranschluss</td>
                    <td>Zoll / IG</td>
                    <td>1/2 " ; Aussengewinde</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Abwasseranschluss</td>
                    <td>Zoll / IG</td>
                    <td>1/2 " ; Aussengewinde</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Dampfanschluss</td>
                    <td>Flansch / DN</td>
                    <td>DN 50 / PN 16</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Kondensatanschluss</td>
                    <td>Flansch / DN</td>
                    <td>DN 32 /  PN 16</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Ölanschluss</td>
                    <td>mm</td>
                    <td>10 mm Kupferleitung</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table></div>
            </div>
            <!-- END Columns Tabelle -->

        </div>
        <!--.row-->
```

[image: Issue 1: Click on button 2 and collapse table 1]

[image: The button "float" on right]

Comment: Is the problem still there? Because I can't reproduce it on your website...

Answer (score 0):

add an id to your first `.row` and use that id in a `data-parent` attribute on the button to specify its parent:

```
<div class="row" id="tableParent">
    ...
    <button class="btn" data-parent="tableParent" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#table1" class="table1" style="margin-bottom: 20px; width: 100% !important; background: #fadf3e; color:#000;">Stritzel PS 200-15</button>
    ...
```

Comment: you may also want to contain the first two columns in their own row

Comment: check the documentation for bootstrap collapse here:
[Bootstrap JS Collapse Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Apply float:right; property for the 2nd table (EDI 40)

```
<div class="col-md-6 table2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.table2{
    float:right !important;
}
```